# How do I get the database url of AWS EC2 MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to import gtfs files into mysql by using a tool from github, runing the follwoing command:

```
gtfsdb-load --database_url <db url>  <gtfs file | url>
```

How can I get the `database_url` of mysql located in AWS EC2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running MySQL on AWS EC2 as an RDS instance, your `database_url` will be the RDS instance name (followed by :port of course).

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html for more info, but this is normally of the form `myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` (where `us-east-1` is the region in this example but might vary depending on your setup).

Alternatively, if you're running your own MySQL installation on an EC2 instance, you'll need to use your instance's public IP address or external DNS hostname. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses for more info on this. If you're doing this, you will have to have permitted ingress to your instance on the MySQL port, using Security Groups.

Comment: thx. How to specify a database? (there are several databases in my instance). Something like `--database_url mysql://myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/gtfs`?

Comment: Yip. It looks like gtfsdb uses SQLAlchemy. And that follows the RFC-1738 format, like so: `dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database`. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#database-urls

Answer (score 1):

***Nix/Windows**

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query "*[].[DBInstanceIdentifier,Endpoint.Address,Endpoint.Port,MasterUsername]"
```

This will dump the required connection properties for all RDS instances in your account, along with enough info to tell them apart.

Adapted from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html (from [thatdamncat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996824/thatdamncat) answer)